# Sharepoint App: Create a list using javascript on the host web, list does not appear on site content

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin

So here I am creating a list on a sharepoint app, the app has full control over the host web.
I run the code and it does not trigger any exception, but If I check the host site contents, the list does not appear. Is this a normal behavior?

The group creates without any problem

here's a chunk of the code:

```
    var hostWebContext = new SP.ClientContext(PoxtaOnline.Utils.Url.getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'))
    var hostWeb = hostWebContext.get_web();
    var groupCreateInfo = new SP.GroupCreationInformation();
    var listCreateInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    var siteGroups = hostWeb.get_siteGroups();
    var siteLists = hostWeb.get_lists();

    groupCreateInfo.set_title(_self.name());
    groupCreateInfo.set_description('Grupo de usuarios correspondiente a la seccion de ' + _self.name());

    listCreateInfo.set_title(_self.name());
    listCreateInfo.set_description('Biblioteca de documentos de Poxta Online para la seccion ' + _self.name());
    listCreateInfo.set_quickLaunchOption(SP.QuickLaunchOptions.off);
    listCreateInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.documentLibrary);

    asyncObjects.sectionGroup = siteGroups.add(groupCreateInfo);
    asyncObjects.sectionList = siteLists.add(listCreateInfo);

    hostWebContext.load(asyncObjects.sectionGroup);
    hostWebContext.load(asyncObjects.sectionList);
    SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notification);
    notification = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Creando grupo de usuarios y biblioteca de documentos...', true);
    hostWebContext.executeQueryAsync(onCreateGroupAndListSuccess, onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, changed

```
var hostWebContext = new SP.ClientContext(PoxtaOnline.Utils.Url.getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'))
```

for

```
var hostWebContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, PoxtaOnline.Utils.Url.getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'))
```

and changed this

```
hostWebContext.load(asyncObjects.sectionGroup);
hostWebContext.load(asyncObjects.sectionList);
SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notification);
notification = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Creando grupo de usuarios y biblioteca de documentos...', true);
hostWebContext.executeQueryAsync(onCreateGroupAndListSuccess, onError);
```

for this

```
context.load(asyncObjects.sectionGroup);
context.load(asyncObjects.sectionList);
SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notification);
notification = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Creando grupo de usuarios y biblioteca de documentos...', true);
context.executeQueryAsync(onCreateGroupAndListSuccess, onError);
```